# How to make an Avalonia UI compatible bitmap in code?

Tags: avaloniaui

I wish to have a background bitmap in my Avalonia application. Getting it displayed is easy, it is making one in code that is hard.

For display, I have in my main window xaml:

```
  <Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush Source="{Binding BackgroundImage}"/>
  </Window.Background>
```

I can load a bitmap into the view model just fine using:

```
  Bitmap loader = new Bitmap( @"C:\image.BMP");
  _backgroundImage = loader;
```

So, now all I want to do is have the text "A2" (for example) made into a bitmap using code instead.

I've done a lot of experimenting and looking at samples, and the closest I have is:

```
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
var text = new FormattedText();
text.Text = "A2";
var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(new PixelSize(width, height));
using (IDrawingContextImpl ctx = bitmap.CreateDrawingContext(null))
{
  ctx.DrawText(brush, new Point(0, 0), text); // last param error
}
_backgroundImage = bitmap;
```

Which is fine apart from the fact that the text variable "cannot convert from 'Avalonia.Media.FormattedText' to 'Avalonia.Platform.IFormattedTextImpl'". I've experimented around it, tried to work out what is different between this and the Avalonia code, but got stuck. What am I missing please? (Yes, I've not got the details of the text size done yet - need to get the basics working first).

Answer (score 1):

As of versions 0.9 and 0.10 you can convert `IDrawingContextImpl` to a proper `DrawingContext` by passing it to the constructor.

The API is higly likely to be changed in 0.11, so RenderTargetBitmap will be usable only for rendering *controls* and a different `Bitmap` class could be used for immediate-mode drawing.

Comment: Thanks - adding a line to do that makes it compile, but it gives an error in the DrawText that the FormattedText is not set up properly (null values). I've played with a static bitmap further, and the opacity doesn't go well for what I need - white areas get darker, black areas are as black, and I need the opposite - and tiling doesn't work, so I shall abandon this idea for now, and try again at some point. Suffice to say, being able to do a low intensity background for a window would be nice to have.